# Calculate Median in SQL for the particular data set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Data Set as below and need to calculate median for that set.

Below Data Set is a growing Data set. Just display only the first 2 Ids.

[image]

Need to display it as group by with ID,Month and Section

[image]

I tried it with the PERCENTILE_CONT() and the NTILE(). But Could get the proper out put.

NTILE()

```
SELECT ID,[Month],Section,MAX(BestTime) AS Median
FROM (
 SELECT ID,[Month],Section,BestTime,
 NTILE(4) OVER(PARTITION BY ,[bestCT] ORDER BY Section,BestTime) AS Quartile 
    from MonthlyCycleTime SK
) X
WHERE Quartile = 2
ID,[Month],Section
```

PERCENTILE_CONT()

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID,[Month],Section,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BestTime) OVER(PARTITION BY Section,BestTime)) AS Median
from MonthlyCycleTime SK
```

Please help me to solve the code and get proper out put with the Median Value

Comment: I tried this examples also. But No Luck

Comment: Why didn't it work, @KH19 ? Your *images* ([Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)) doesn't have any expected results, and we can't run your code (again, *images*), so we have no idea why are you aren't getting the output you want.